# Check if DOM element is editable (allow user input) with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  switch (key) {
      case 38: ui.action.up(); break;
      case 40: ui.action.down(); break;
      case 37: ui.action.left(); break;
      case 39: ui.action.right(); break;
  }
  return false;
});
```

in code that implement **2048** game.

I have user forms and want to exit from handler if `document.activeElement` point to `input`or `textarea` or `select` as handler break ability to perform normal edit operation for users.

Currently I see two paths for such check:

```
["INPUT", "TEXTAREA", "SELECT"].indexOf(document.activeElement.nodeName) > -1
```

and:

```
document.activeElement instanceof HTMLInputElement
    || document.activeElement instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement
    || document.activeElement instanceof HTMLSelectElement
```

What is a portable way and what is the best that confirm to HTML 5 standard and what is a shortest one?

**UPDATE** I try 3rd strategy - check for properties that unique for editable elements. From standard http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html with help of `undescore.js`:

```
var good = _.intersection(Object.keys(HTMLInputElement.prototype),
                          Object.keys(HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype),
                          Object.keys(HTMLSelectElement.prototype))
var bad = _.union(Object.keys(HTMLObjectElement.prototype),
                  Object.keys(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype),
                  Object.keys(HTMLDivElement.prototype),
                  Object.keys(HTMLButtonElement));
 console.log(_.difference(good, bad));
```

I get the list:

```
 "autofocus", "disabled", "required", "value"
```

So I stop with:

```
if (document.activeElement.value) { ... }
```

checks!

Comment: The first one seems fine, I'd probably throw in a `toUppercase` to be safe though !

Comment: @adeneo Agree, I just read: http://ejohn.org/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/ +1

Comment: `/^(input|textarea|select)$/i.test(document.activeElement.nodeName)` is another option if you're looking for short. The `i` flag solves the case issue. (Also if you're looking for short you can say `switch(event.keyCode || event.which)`, you don't need to create a variable that is only used once after it is assigned a value.)

Comment: P.S. Note that just because an element is an input or has a `value` property doesn't mean it is "editable": it could be a button, or it could be `readonly` or disabled, etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn In my case `readonly` or `disabled` element can't get focus (never be a value of `document.activeElement`). Am I wrong?

Comment: `readonly` elements can [definitely get focus](http://jsfiddle.net/wad73454/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer confirms standards, elegant, but may lack of portability:

```
if (document.activeElement.value) { ... }
```

Comment: won't work for elements with contenteditable="true" attribute